# Can't load balance two frontend linux VMs in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-load-balancer

I have a 2 tier application up and running and it is generally working well for going from nothing to deployed in 6 days (hurray!) -- but now I'd like to add a 2nd Linux frontend VM for load balancing and fault tolerance.

Here's what I'm done:

1. I stopped the existing frontend VM and captured an image.
2. I then created it again so there is a "azul-frontend.cloudapp.net" based off of this image.
3. I then attempted to create a 2nd clone from the image called "azul-frontend2" but when I get to the "VM Mode" blade in the creation UI in the portal, when I select "CONNECT TO EXISTING VIRTUAL MACHINE" both the machine selection dropdown and the "REGION/AFFINITY GROUP/VIRTUAL NETWORK" dropdowns are blank and unselectable.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong - any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, was the machine in the Azul-frontend.cloudapp.net fully running when you went to set up the second one?  I've noticed that when going through the portal I have had to wait until the first machine in the cloud service was completely up and responding before the option for the Connect to existing virtual machine to get populated.

Comment: yup - it was running. :(